# Why isn't "has"... the beginning of a valid JavaBean method signature?

Tags: java, javabeans

The JavaBeans methods' signature's has to follow certain conventions such as set.../get... and such. They have a convention for is...for instance `isEven()` could be a method for an Integer  class to test a boolean. But then I wonder why not has... is also a legal identifier since it makes sense to me to test what something has e.g. `hasCar()` for a Person class or likewise.

Do you understand my question? What do you think?

Comment: They could has added a number of question words, but AFAIK they tried to keep them to a minimum.

Comment: This always drove me a little nuts too.  I'm not a big fan of the "is" convention.  Even worse when it gets generated like isHasCar()

Comment: `hasXxx` could be confused with `getXxx() != null`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the general convention is to use `get...` and `set...` and thus `is...` is just an exception for booleans. For `is...` the convention is easy: you need to return a boolean, can skip the getter and the corresponding setter will take a boolean parameter as well.

A convention for `has...` would be more difficult: `has...` would return a boolean but you'd still need a getter and setter which deal with different types. Thus `has...` is no replacement for `get...` as opposed to `is...` and since that part of the JavaBeans convention normally only is about getters and setters `has...` doesn't fit in there.

From the JavaBeans spec:

> Properties are discrete, named attributes of a Java Bean...
>
> Properties show up in a number of ways:
>
> 1. ...
> 2. Properties can be accessed programmatically by other components calling their *getter*
>    and *setter* methods (see Section 7.1 below).
> 3. ...

Any property being accessed using `has...` would not be persistent nor be accessed by its getter method.

Example: if a person has a `car` property, you'd expect to have a `getCar()` accessor. `hasCar()` wouldn't be an accessor since the derived property `hasCar` would need an accessor named  `getHasCar()` or `isHasCar()`. If `has` was an accessor prefix, the property would have the conflicting name `car`.

Comment: @Programmer400, @Mike: How about `isWith`? The property would then be `withCar` and can be accessed by `isWithCar`.

Comment: `if (valueDescription.isToBeDisplayed())` is somehow awkward to me. 
I still prefer to write `if (valueDescription.shallBeDisplayed())`. :)

Comment: @LarsJuelJensen that's ok if all people working on the code are able to understand it and unless you want to use JavaBeans - which the question and answer was about. In that case you'll have to at least provide another getter that starts with `get` or `is` (and btw, what would be the setter for `shallBeDisplayed`?).

Comment: My code usually ends up into something like `vd.isVisible()` and `vd.setVisible(boolean isVisible)` - to go with the flow. :) - it just takes a little time to get out of the 'shall/has' property name that naturally comes to me to bend and turn it into something 'is'-friendly :)

Comment: @LarsJuelJensen you can replace the ankwardness with specific objects: ```if(valueDescription.getDisplayOptions().isShow()```, but I do like calling shall, fire, do and has too

Answer (score 1):

`get/set` and `is/set` for boolean type is just the convention. I agree that sometimes it is more readable to call getter `hasSomething`. For example `hasChildren()`. But let's go forward and say that it is fine to call method `canWrite()` or `willFly()` or `providesResult()` etc. And you can use such names but these names are not following java bean convention and therefore will not be recognized as getters by java bean frameworks.

Java Beans were invented a lot of years ago. Probably it is not a bad idea to define annotations `@Setter` and `@Getter`. If these annotations become common all java bean frameworks could support them and programmers will be able to call getters as they want but mark them with annotation `@Getter`. But such annotations are not supported now, so the only advise is to follow existing naming conventions.

Comment: I like the idea of having `@Setter` and `@Getter` annotations.

Comment: I like that you like my idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is a bad question at all! I thought about that too and found that people do use it [like you intend to use it](http://ugate.wordpress.com/2012/06/). It's just that most libraries (like the one you propably use) don't.

I agree that it should be valid for boolean properties.