# property does not follow javabean conventions

Tags: java, javabeans, conventions

I am using java 1.7, WAS 8 (Clustered env)

I have property defined in my java class as,

```
@AsserTrue(groups=verifiedruleset.class,mesage={some message}
public boolean hasShortName(){
   boolean myflag=true;
   some condition;
   return myflag;
}
```

When I try to save record I am getting error as 'property hasShortName does not follow javabean conventions. 
This error occurring in WAS clustered environment.

but ,if used shared libraries(libs of spring,logging,commons..etc) in clustered environment , it is working fine.
Also ,In WAS Non clustered environment , it is working fine.

But now I want to remove , shared libraries in clustered environment , during which I am getting above error.

I tried with [Why isn't "has"... the beginning of a valid JavaBean method signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934866/why-isnt-has-the-beginning-of-a-valid-javabean-method-signature) and tried as isHasShortName() but it is giving error for setter not defined.

Can anyone please suggest what is wrong here..

Comment: If your expected property name is "shortName", the getter should be either "getShortName" or "isShortName"

Comment: Method name should be isShortName() not isHasShortName.

Comment: I will try with isShortName , do I need to provide empty setter also ?

Comment: Tried with isShortName, it gave setter not defined error. But I am not sure what will be setter.Since there is no variable defined for shortName in the class, but have only hasShortName() .Also tried with changing name from hasShortName() to checkShortName() , it gave error as annonated must follow javabean convension, checkShortName()  do not.  Also as mentioned above hasShortName is working with Shared library,but when removed shared libs it is not working. So is it someting to any jar file I need to add or upgrade ? or what should be setter as there is no field shortName.

Comment: can someone please suggest something here

Comment: i tried with getter and setter and it is Working fine in WAS 8.5 environment which is "NON CLUSTERED". But it is "NOT" working in clustered environment. So looks like it is some jar issue from Websphere which is overriding my application jar in clustered env. I will raise another question and if any WAS person can help me there.